# How count[index]++ counts the identical ekements in an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new in problem solving. I tried this problem from leetcode [Number of good pairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-good-pairs/description/?source=submission-ac) and I solved using double loops. But later in solutions I got a better solution.
That's my code:

```
`        
    public int numIdenticalPairs(int[] nums) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++){
                if(nums[i]==nums[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
`
```

and the better solution is this:

```
`    
    public int numIdenticalPairs(int[] A) {
        int res = 0, count[] = new int[101];
        for (int a: A) {
            res += count[a]++;
        }
        return res;
    }
`
```

But I don't understand how count[a]++ can count all the identical elements? Can anyone explain this for me? #TIA

Comment: Try running the code in a debugger. Set a break point at `int res = 0, count [] = new int [101];` and then run the code one-step-at-a-time. At each step, check the values of the variables.

Comment: TIL `int res = 0, count[] = new int[101];` is valid syntax.

Comment: The value at _count[a]_ will only increase for _a_.  Similar to what _@Shovel_Knight_ said, this would not work with negative numbers, additionally, you'd have to find the maximum value first, to set the size of _count_.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand how a program works is to run it in a debugger. This would allow you to see its internal state.

This particular solution works in the following way:

1. When the array `count[]` is initialized, every element inside it is equal to 0.
2. As the enhanced for loop `for (int a : A)` goes through the original array, every time it encounters a number, it increments `count[a]` by 1, but only *after* the assignment `res += count[a]++`.

For example, if you take one of their example arrays `{1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3}`:

`res += count[1]++` -> `res == 0, count[1] == 1`

`res += count[2]++` -> `res == 0, count[2] == 1`

`res += count[3]++` -> `res == 0, count[3] == 1`

`res += count[1]++` -> `res == 1, count[1] == 2`

`res += count[1]++` -> `res == 3, count[1] == 3`

`res += count[3]++` -> `res == 4, count[3] == 2`

It's a clever solution but very much tailored to their particular test cases because you are limited by the size of `count[]`. What if integers inside the original array are larger than 100? What if there are negative numbers?

Comment: Thanks for such generous explanations @Shovel_Knight

Answer (score 1):

Consider that for any repeated values, `(e.g.1,1,1,1,1)` the count of subarrays is `1,3,6,10` for `(1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1,1), and (1,1,1,1,1)` respectively.  Notice the deltas between the consecutive terms for the pattern are `2,3,and 4`.  Those deltas increment by `1` so the solution for the `nth` value is `n*(n-1)/2`. Where `n = 1` initially.

To compute that solution in a loop for `5 of the same value` do it as follows;

```
int delta = 0;
int res = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
   res = res + delta;
   delta++;
}
System.out.println(res);
```

prints

```
10
```

This is exactly what your loop is doing. But I am changing `count[]` to `delta[]` since it more describes what that array contains.

- the array is initialized to `101` to access deltas for values from `0 to 100` inclusive.  By default deltas are all `0`.  They are considered the initial deltas for all possible values.
- Then as you iterate them you are do the following.
- `res += delta[a]++;`  Where `a` is used as an index into it's own delta array to sum the good pairs.  It is first used as `0` since one value does not constitute a pair. It them bumps the delta by `1` for the next occurrence of the same value of `a`.

So here is a more verbose solution which does the same thing as yours.

```
public static int numIdenticalPairs(int[] A) {
     int res = 0;
     int[] deltas = new int[101];
     for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
         int value = A[i];          // get the value from the array
         int delta = deltas[value]; // get current delta for that value
         res += delta;              // adjust the pair count for all values
         deltas[value] = delta + 1; // increment delta for next occurrence of value.
     }
     return res;
}
```